# Passing all parameters as array and changing one of them

Tags: symfony, twig

I am passing an array of get arguments from controller to twig template, and then create a link:

```
{{ url('route_name', array_of_get_parameters) }}
```

It works, but what if I want to pass all BUT ONE of those parameters unchanged? Something like:

```
{{ url('route_name', array_of_get_parameters, {'param1': 'value'}) }}
```

The example above doesn't work of course...is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can't you just add the unchanged parameter to the array inside the controller action?

Answer (score 2):

Use `twig` [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) filter like this:

```
{{ url('route_name', array_of_get_parameters|merge({'param1': 'value'})) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.
Instead override the value in the controller (<- better) or in the twig template, before the url generation.